# Contacts are not Showing on Device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Hello every one i am stuck in problem while fetching user contacts. i write some code for that and its working fine in simulator its showing user names and there numbers . Now when i am testing on Device nothing is appear. please see my code what is wrong with this .

```
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
#import <Contacts/Contacts.h>
```

i import these in my .H file  and here is code for .M

```
    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (granted == YES) {
        //keys with fetching properties
        NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
        NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
        NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
        } else {
            for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {

                NSLog(@"print contacts %@",contact.givenName);

                for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {
                    NSString *phone = [label.value stringValue];
                    if ([phone length] > 0) {

                        NSLog(@"Print Phone no %@",phone);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

its working fine in simulator but its not working on my Device please Help .

Comment: You cannot access files outside of your own applications sandbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No, all apps on iOS run in a Sandbox, this means they only have access to files and folders within their own "workspace". iOS 8 has brought along shared containers which apps can use to share documents and files between themselves, but this only extends to apps in the same "App Group", generally an App and it's extension. Meaning you cannot access other application's files unless they are explicitly given to you via a share extension. As this extensions are called on user request, an app cannot pass these files around in the background and certainly not when being uninstalled. When applications are uninstalled iOS automatically prompts the user that documents/data will be lost, however network stored data/documents may still be available.

More Information about the File System Sandbox: [Apple Doc's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW13)

iOS8 Document Provider - [Accessing Files Outside Your Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/AccessingDocuments/AccessingDocuments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014451-CH2-SW9) - This is a user initiated process.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply . can this could be done in ios 8 with swift implementing the extensions for very basic purpose like images , videos or some audio files

Comment: In theory yes. But there are restrictions as mentioned in the answer above

Comment: thanks again for simple and short answer